# Umbrella plant drooping leaves

Tags: houseplants

I have an umbrella plant and the bottom leaves drooping could someone tell me why this might be. I have tried putting it in direct light, longer between watering, watering more frequently and have given it plant food. But those leaves always seem to die and droop.

Comment: pictures please